# mysql ndbcluster increase maxnoofattributes

Tags: mysql

How to increase maxnoofattributes? I get the following error:

> Error: increase maxnoofattributes while altering tables

This is my config file:

```
[root@ClusterMgm ~]# cat /etc/mycluster.cnf

[NDBD DEFAULT]
NoOfReplicas=2
DataMemory=64M
IndexMemory=18M
MaxNoOfTables=1024
MaxNoOfAttributes=5000000
MaxNoOfOrderedIndexes=10000
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Without posting your code you risk removal of your question. And finish the tour!

Comment: https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2):

What is your current "MaxNoOfAttributes" value? Check it using "`ndb_config -q MaxNoOfAttributes`" command.

Change MaxNoOfAttributes value in your mysql-cluster config.ini file as shown in above question.
Then you have to restart cluster to take effect of this change.

Restart Process:

> kill $(pidof ndb_mgmd)
>
> ndb_mgmd --skip-config-cache -f /etc/mycluster.cnf

Then restart your data node from "**ndb_mgm**" console using "**{nodeId} restart**" command (i.e. 2 restart).

And check again your current "MaxNoOfAttributes" value.

**Note:**
The default value for MaxNoOfAttributes is 1000, with the minimum possible value being 32 and The maximum is 4294967039.

You can check more information from this [page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-cluster-excerpt/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-ndbd-definition.html#ndbparam-ndbd-maxnoofattributes).

Comment: Thank u for reply